# How to use Fetch api to post text/plain

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I try to use `Fetch()` API to post `text/plain` :

```
fetch('/test', {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    },
    body: "this is a test"
  })
 .then(response => response.text())
 .then(body => {
    console.log(body)
 })
```

This is the router that deal with the request

```
router.post('/test',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body)
    res.send('OK')
})
```

However, the output of `console.log(req.body)` is `{}`.

I think the problem is the code after `body:` I don't know what is the right way to post text/plain data.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things you can try to troubleshoot the issue:

Make sure you're using a middleware like body-parser to parse the request body. Without it, the `req.body` object will be empty.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// your routes...
```

You can try using `FormData` on the client-side to send the data as a `multipart/form-data` instead of `text/plain`.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('text', 'this is a test');

fetch('/test', {
  method: 'post',
  body: formData
})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(body => {
  console.log(body);
});
```

If you still want to use text/plain, you can try sending the data as a `stringified JSON object`.

```
fetch('/test', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    text: 'this is a test'
  })
})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(body => {
  console.log(body);
});
```

Then on the server-side, you can access the data with `req.body.text`.

I hope this helps you solve the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Here, bodyparser.text middleware will only parse the request coming with the type of `text/plain`.

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const PORT = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.text({
  type: 'text/plain'
}));

// DESC: Route to handle test
// Method: POST
// Access: PUBLIC
app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send('OK');
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running at http://localhost:${PORT}`));
```